# Use closed loop torque control based on motor position to simulate a dynamic load

Tags: servo, vfd

The goal is to use servo + gearbox to simulate a screwing process millions of times.

A screwing process is characterized by a low torque at first (the screw enters the material) and once the screw head touches the surface a steep torque curve starts. See the attached image (a).

Example of a torque ramp: 5% to 90% of max motor torque within 2 rotations or 720deg

I believe I can realize this screwing-simulator with a closed-loop torque control on a variable frequency drive (VFD) like Siemens S120 and using a synchronous motor servo like type 1FT7 and a torque sensor. The torque setpoint of the VFD needs to be updated based on the measured angle (external encoder).

The simulator is basically a motor in regenerative mode, thus requiring a brake resistor.

Is this concept of a screwing simulator reasonable?

How accurately can I control the torque?

If the torque setpoint is set to zero, will the servo (that is behind a gearbox) just rotate when I apply torque by hand? (see attached illustration (b) of the thought experiment)

[image: screwing curve and thought experiment setup]

Comment: Screw process torque depends a lot on the screw type and material; a woodscrew and a machine bolt will be entirely different, and in the woodscrew's case it depends on whether the hole has been correctly double-drilled and countersunk or not.

Comment: Your soft-joint graph is perhaps optimistic...as torque requirements increase due to screwing deeper, force required to keep the driver engaged in the screw head also increases. This high thrust increases drag on motor (thrust) bearing. A hex-head screw could help - must your solution accommodate *any* type of screw head?

Comment: Sorry, but I think I wasn't clear enough in the text. The motor is not applying torque to any screw. This is a screw-simulator to which an electrical drill (not mentioned in the post) will apply a torque. It is part of a drill-testing system. The torque graph is just how a `soft screw case` is specified for test machine manufacturers.

Comment: why do you want to use a motor instead of a brake?